Many interactions with GestureDetector > onScaleUpdate and just one rebuild
`I have a problem with GestureDetector's onScaleUpdate.
When I perform a pan, for multiple scales it only builds my widget once.
GestureDetector logic with a ref.read (riverpod)
My widget
output
I want to have a build for each scale.
expected output exemple
